# Javascript Close a div layer when mouse hovers off div?

Tags: javascript

trying to get a piece of code to work like this:

static image is use to trigger a div to slide in from the bottom of the page, mouse will already be on top of that div, once the mouse pulls away and of that div, i want the div to slide back down the way it came from, here is what i have so far on opening and closing...

```
var clicked=true;
$(".one").on('click', function(){
    if(clicked)
    {
        clicked=false;
        $(".two").css({"bottom": 0});
    }
    else
    {
        clicked=true;
        $(".two").css({"bottom": "-700px"});
    }
});
```

instead of clicking it to close since it will overlap the button, the mouse moving off the div for it to do so automatically is ideal..

TIA

attempted to run on my local machine atm...

online fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/heisenberg5711/v6n2pgm3/#&togetherjs=9EsLosEert

Comment: Please present a proper [mre] of your issue when asking this kind of question, and not just snippets that lack context.

Comment: What have you actually tried then? The code you have shown handles click events only. Where is your _attempt_ to implement any sort of mouse leave event handler?

Comment: Provide the other part of the functionality. Without that, it's impossible to find where the problem is. By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/heisenberg5711/v6n2pgm3/#&togetherjs=9EsLosEert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your way of doing this is not clean. I mean there is a better way fot doing it (search about it ), but you can
change your JS to :

```
$(".one").hover( function(){
   
        //clicked=false;
        $(".two").css({"bottom": 0});
    }
    
    );
    $(".two").hover( function(){
   
        //clicked=false;
        $(".two").css({"bottom": 0});
    },function()
    {
        //clicked=true;
        $(".two").css({"bottom": "-700px"});
    },
    
    );
```

Comment: glad to heard it

Comment: would it be possible with the div .one when its clicked only instead of a hover?

Comment: yes off course , for doing that you only need on('click) method to add on your div